# how to make a property to be "merged" or initialized when deserializing with JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm using JMSSerializer - along with the Doctrine constructor - in order to deserialize an object sent.

My (simplified) entities are the following. I omit the code I think is useless:

```
Widget
{
   protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Belka\Iso50k1Bundle\Entity\VarSelection",
     *     mappedBy="widget",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove", "detach", "merge"})
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o-all-getCWidget", "i-p2-create", "o-all-getWidget", "i-p3-create", "i-p2-editWidget"})
     * @Type("ArrayCollection<Belka\Iso50k1Bundle\Entity\VarSelection>")
     */
    protected $varsSelection;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 *
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(
 *     name="vartype",
 *     type="string")
 *
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "PHY" = "PhyVarSelection"
 * })
 * 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class VarSelection
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue("SEQUENCE")
     * @Serializer\groups({"o-all-getCWidget", "o-all-getWidget", "i-p2-editWidget"})
     */
protected $id;
}



class PhyVarSelection extends VarSelection
{
    /**
     * @var PhyVar
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="Belka\Iso50k1Bundle\Entity\PhyVar",
     *     cascade={"persist", "merge", "detach"})
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="phy_var_sel",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     nullable=false)
     */
    protected $phyVar;
}

class PhyVar extends Variable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o-p2-getCMeters", "o-all-getWidget"})
     * @Assert\Regex("/(PHY)_\d+_\d+_\w+/")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="varname")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o-p2-getCMeters", "o-all-getWidget", "o-all-getCWidget"})
     */
    protected $varName;

    ...

}
```

I try to deserialize an object that represents a `Widget` entity already persisted, along with which an array of `varselection` with their own `id` specified - if already persisted - and without their own `id` if they are new and to be persisted.

Deserialization works:

```
$context = new DeserializationContext();
$context->setGroups('i-p2-editWidget');
$data = $this->serializer->deserialize($content, $FQCN, 'json', $context);
```

but `$data` has always `Widget::$varsSelection[]::$phyVar` as a proxy class initialized, with only the `id` properly set. What I have to do so as to have it all is:

```
foreach ($data->getVarsSelection() as $varSel) {
    $varSel->getVar();
}
```

why is that? How can have it initialized already? I don't want to spend time cycling and fetching data from DB again.

**edit**

I've added a domain of the entities so as to get the idea of what I'm deserializing
[image: Domain of the entities]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself the hows and whys of this behavior:

since I'm sending a JSON like the following:

```
{
  "id": <widgetID>,
  "vars_selection": {
    "id": <varSelectionID>,
    "vartype": "PHY"
  }
}
```

JMSSerializer's Doctrine `ObjectConstructor` simply tries to finds just two Entities: `Widget` and `VarSelection` by executing the following line:

```
$object = $objectManager->find($metadata->name, $identifierList);
```

in other words: Doctrine's `EntityManager` tries to find the Entity identified by its ID. Hence, well'get the unitialized proxy classes.

As far as I know, `find` cannot specify an hydration mode. Hence, two are the ways to handle this:

1. Specify `fetch="EAGER"` on `PhyVarSelection::$phyVar`. Quite costly, when we do not need it though;
2. Replace the `ObjectConstructor` by calling the repository and make a DQL, which will have the `EAGER` option properly set. Something like `$query->setFetchMode("PhyVarSelection", "phyVar", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);`